# info needed about soap over smtp

Tags: java, soap, smtp

I am new to soap and I am wondering if the following would work. I could use it to communicate between difficult to reach servers.

Suppose I have a server somewhere on an intranet, I cannot reach by http, but I can send and receive mails from that server. I also have another server somewhere on the internet, where I can also send and receive mails.

Can I by using soap over smtp, make remote calls to that server and receive remote calls from that server with the other server.

Also, would I be needing reachable mail servers for both servers or is it possible to encapsulate mail servers in the code on both servers ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is certainly possible, since SOAP messages are just XML documents. In fact, the SOAP 1.2 specification contains a [SOAP over email](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-soap12-part0-20011217/#SMTP) section.

Comment: ty for the response ! And the part of my question about needing reachable mail servers and it being possible to encapsulate those in my code; can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: There are zillions of ways to send and receive email using Java, both with internal and external servers. I don't really know what would be best for your situation.

Comment: ok, ty, a zillion you say; I should be able to find one then.